# Preference page not displaying in widow preferences list of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]
I'm new to Eclipse plugin development.
I created an simple editor plugin project in Eclise and then adding preference page for that editor like below in plugin.xml.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
      <page class="org.myEditor.preferencesPage.GeneralPreferencePage"
            id="myLanguagePreferencePage"
            name="My Language">
      </page>

      <page id="myLanguageEditor"
            name="Editor"
            class="org.myEditor.preferencesPage.EditorPreferencePage"
            category="myLanguagePreferencePage">
      </page>
</extension>
```

But above preference page is listing inside 'Others' section of Preferences (In eclipse, Window > Preferences > Others).

Can any one help me how to show preference page in preferences list (Window > Preferences) only not inside Others section.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - the preferences display with a top level of 'My Language' with a nested 'Editor' preference.

Comment: I didn't get which of your 2 preference pages is placed wrong. Could you post a screenshot of your Preferences tree?

Comment: I have attached screen shot of Preference page.
From the image attached, 'My Language' appears inside 'Others' section.
But I want it to be as like C/C++ preferences.